# Having error while building Ruby from trunk on OSX

Tags: ruby

I am trying to build ruby from source and here are the steps I'm following;

1. Fetch the latest version from Github, `git pull upstream trunk`
2. Run `./configure`
3. Run `make`

The output of the 3rd command is;

```
./revision.h unchanged
generating enc.mk
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from ./enc/make_encmake.rb:121:in `<main>'
./enc/make_encmake.rb:100:in `target_transcoders': undefined method `-' for #<Dir:./enc/trans> (NoMethodError)
make: *** [enc.mk] Error 1
```

I don't really know how it's supposed to work because there is no `#-`(extract) method for Dir instances in none of the Ruby versions.

Comment: I've just successfully built revision 65b1cf0 on Ubuntu 18.10. [Line 100 of make_encmake.rb](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/65b1cf0e82255db68262dfb8fdb001268981e223/enc/make_encmake.rb#L100) is supposed to be calling `#-` on an `Array`, not a `Dir` (the result of the `Dir.open` block assigned to `trans` from line 90). The only way `trans` could be `Dir` is if no block was passed to `open`. Do you have any local changes to `enc/make_encmake.rb`?

Comment: How **exactly** do you recreate your setup? `git clone https://github.com/ruby/ruby; cd ruby; git pull upstream trunk` returns `fatal: 'upstream' does not appear to be a git repository`. It looks like you've forked the repository, so explain in more detail please.

Comment: @anothermh upstream is `git@github.com:ruby/ruby.git`, it's a convention. origin targets to my fork and upstream targets to ruby's repository.

Comment: @PhilRoss `Dir.open` with given block on line 90 returns an instance of `Dir` instead of an `Array` on my setup. I tried to run the same code(`Dir.open` with block) in IRB session and it correctly returns an Array.

Comment: ok, I've found the problem. I made some changes for `select` method which was causing the problem because somehow the make target is using the recently built ruby version instead of base ruby version.

Comment: make_encmake.rb is [run using the miniruby executable](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/65b1cf0e82255db68262dfb8fdb001268981e223/common.mk#L825) that is produced during the Ruby build process.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information @PhilRoss. It's really weird that the make target is using recently built miniruby version which obscures the errors in recent implementation as seen, I'd expect it to use base ruby version.

Comment: That you're trying to compile a fork that you've modified is pretty important information; the title of this question is misleading.